# How can I get list of parameters names from ftl file?

Tags: java, freemarker

I use FreeMarker framework.
I have some template with parameters.
How can I get list of parameters names from my tempalte file?
Thx.

Comment: What exactly do you need? You have an FTL file with references like `${yourParam}`, `${anotherParam}`, etc., and you need a list of such parameter names?

Comment: yes. I resolved this problem with regex.

Comment: OK, that's the way I was about to suggest. Just remember, there is a few [special variables](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html), too, which also gives some unusual ways how to reference a parameter (e.g. via `vars` special variable).

Answer (score 0):

For now (as of 2.3.23), the best you can do is certainly what you did... "parsing" the template yourself. The API with which you can "introspect" the template isn't published and has no backward compatibility guarantees. BTW, it's planned that collecting info about the used variables will be a 2.3.24 feature, but that's far away and uncertain.

Also this thing has an inherent problem. As you can refer variables dynamically (like `.vars[dynamicName]`), and as sometimes it's not obvious if you refer to a data-model variable or an `#assign`-ed (or `#global`-ed or `#local`-ed) variable, it's not possible with 100% precision. It's not like Java, some things will only turn out on runtime.